# What is difference between <scope> and <phase> in maven plugin (jbehave example)

Tags: maven, jbehave-plugin

As in title - here is piece of code.

I can have < scope > as well as < phase >

Jbehave documentation doesn't say much about it (http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html)

```
               <execution>
                    <id>run-stories</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Stories*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<phase/>` element/property is a "standard" Maven property that indicates which phase of the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) the execution will occur in.

The `<scope/>` element/property you're referring to is specific to the JBehave plugin itself. Per the plugin's documentation, it seems that `<scope/>` is used to control which "set" of your project's Maven dependencies will be included in the JBehave plugin run. Per [this answer on the JBehave site](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/examples-philosophy.html), it seems that, typically, JBehave is executed using only the project's `main` dependencies and code, not the `test` dependencies and code.